# Why can't I access properties in a nested JS Object? (Firebase Snapshot)

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, foreach, firebase-realtime-database

TLDR: please scroll to part after JSON-snippet ;)

I'm currently working on a Firebase-Project. I'm writing code in JavaScript. Since hours I try to extract data from / write into an object, but for some reason I can't access it's params.

Initially my code looked as follows:

```
exports.updateUsersNewInterest = functions.database.ref('/category/{categoryID}/interest/{interestID}').onCreate(event =>{
        const interestID = event.params.interestID;
        const categoryID = event.params.categoryID;

        var ref = admin.database().ref("/userInterests/");
        ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){

                var userID = childSnapshot.key;
                childSnapshotVal = childSnapshot.val();
                var rawSum = childSnapshotVal.rawSum;
                var rawCount = childSnapshotVal.rawCount;
                var norm = childSnapshotVal.norm;
                rawSum[interestID] = 0;
                rawCount[interestID] = 0;
                var resultObject = {};
                resultObject.norm = norm;
                resultObject.rawCount = rawCount;
                resultObject.rawSum = rawSum;               
                var ref1 = admin.database().ref("userInterests/"+userID);
                return ref1.set(resultObject);
            })
            return true
        })
        return true
})
```

Since for some reason I wasn't able to read the keys out of the single childSnapshot objects in the forEach, I had to use another attempt:

```
exports.updateUsersNewInterest = functions.database.ref('/category/{categoryID}/interest/{interestID}').onCreate(event =>{
        const interestID = event.params.interestID;
        const categoryID = event.params.categoryID;

        //console.log(categoryID);
        //console.log(interestID);

        var ref = admin.database().ref("/userInterests/");
        ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
            var data = snapshot.val();

            var keys = Object.keys(data);
            console.log(typeof snapshot);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
//At this point I cant access any properties
//console.log(data[i][rawSum] for example is NOT working
            //  data[i][rawSum][interestID] = 0;
            //  data[i][rawCount][interestID] = 0;
            }
                var ref1 = admin.database().ref("userInterests/");
                return ref1.set(data);
        })
        return true
})
```

Now the thing is, when I try to console.log the key inside the for-loop, I get the right results. But performing any kind of action related to the properties of either $data or $snapshot (even though var data = snapshot.val() should give me an object?! is not working.

I might have lost some brackets copying the code from sublime to here but the general problem stays the same, even if my code-snippet is not complete here.

The firebase console gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rawSum' of undefined at
```

The object looks as follows:

```
{ '2wewe': 
   { rawCount: 
  { '11': 1,
    '17': 0,
    '18': 0,
    '19': 0,
    '33': 0,
    '35': 0,
    '36': 0,
    '40': 0 },
 rawSum: 
  { '11': 1,
    '17': 0,
    '18': 0,
    '19': 0,
...
```

So if I export a snapshot from Firebase and then extract its values via

```
var values = snapshot.val()
```

I should be able to e.g. writh into it with

```
var abc = values[id]['rawCount'][itemID]
```

or what am I missing?

And why is

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var userID = childSnapshot.key;
```

just giving me "undefined"?

Would really appreciate any clue for my (probable rookie) problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `data[i][rawSum]` != `data[i]["rawSum"]` (or `data[i].rawSum`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[i]` should be `data[keys[i]]`. But you can simply loop over the object keys directly, instead of calling `Object.keys()`:

```
for (key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(data[key].rawSum[interestID]);
        console.log(data[key].rawCount[interestID]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested and it works! Thank you sir.
Since I want to write to "data" and later rewrite the whole object into the database, I left out the if statement. There is no data-set for the given interestID unless I add one in the for-loop now.

So as I understand it, I first go into the first node that has the key [key] and then look one level deeper for the node with the key [interestID]? 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The purpose of the `if` statement is to skip properties that are inherited from the object's prototype. See https://blog.javascripting.com/2014/09/19/when-should-javascript-developers-use-hasownproperty/

Comment: Ok, I migh have been off the track a bit. It's the first time I'm working with a prototype-based language. Thanks for the clarification, it makes absolutely sense!